# Adding custom icon for an input type button in jQuery mobile 1.4.0

Tags: jquery-mobile, icons, jquery-mobile-button

In my jQuery mobile app I have a button , and I added a custom  icon for it , the problem is that when i open the page that contains this button the button is shown firstly without an icon then after 1 second the icon is added , this problem appears only on mobile devices  . Please how can I solve this problem ?

any help would be greatly appreciated..

```
<div data-role="page" id="index">
<div data-role="header" data-theme="b">Main</div>
<div data-role="content"> 

<div  class="ui-btn ui-input-btn  ui-icon-User-Icon UsersBTN" >
<input type="button"  id="Users"  data-inline="true"  value="Users"   data-icon="User-  Icon" data-iconpos="left"/>
</div>


</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.UsersBTN{
   background-color:transparent !important;
   border:none;
}

.UsersBTN.ui-btn .ui-input-btn{
   border: solid grey 3px;
   background:blue;
   color:white !important;
}

.UsersBTN.ui-btn .ui-input-btn.ui-btn-active {
   border: solid white 3px !important;
   background-color:blue; 

}

.ui-icon-User-Icon:after {
   background-image: url(images/user.png);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: 100% 100%;
   background-position: 0% 50%;
   border-radius:0 !important;
   width:38px;
   height:38px;
   margin-top:-18px;
   background-color:transparent;

}
```

Comment: show your content using loading with setTimeout function after 1 sec.

Comment: @VedCan you explain more ? how can i do that ?? since i navigate To this Page which contains the button as follow:  <a href="Page1.html"  id="Page1"  data-transition="none" class="ui-btn" data-role="button"> Page1 </a>

Comment: hide content of this page first then show after 2 sec. <div data-role="content" style="display:none;"> $(document).on("pageshow", "#this_page_id", function(e){
        $.mobile.loading( "show", {
        text: "",
        textVisible: true,
        theme: "z",
        html: ""
        });
        setTimeout(function() {
           
            $.mobile.loading( "hide" );
            $('[data-role="content"]').show();
        }, 2000);
    })

Comment: @VedThanks but  this will delay the Page Showing , which will confuse the user , this solution didn't solve the  base problem it will hide the problem from the user eyes , Why the icon didn't appear on the button once the page opened ? can you help me in answering this Question ? Can we solve this problem using another way ??

Comment: try this way .ui-icon-User-Icon {
            background-image: url(images/user.png);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }
        .ui-icon-User-Icon {
            background-position: 0 50%;
        }  <a href="" data-role="button" id="Users" data-icon="User-Icon" data-iconpos="left">Users</a>
        .ui-icon-User-Icon {
            background-position: 0 50%;
        }